# Insert data into OWL ontology

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, jena, owl

I have a custom OWL ontology and I uploaded into my model like this:

```
    OntModel=ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();

    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(urlFile);   
    model.read(in,"");
```

I get the whole ontology into my model. Now I don't know how to add some data into that model. The data that want to insert must be appropriate with that ontology that I uploaded.

Can you give some hints or markups to do that? I'm very lost here.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the Model API [tutorial](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html) useful for learning how to work with a Jena model.  Further, the Jena [javadocs](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/index.html) are always a good reference.

The tutorial will show you how to add data to your Model.

I'm not sure what you mean by "appropriate" with the ontology.  You can just start stating facts in RDF; if you state something that contradicts your ontology, it's state is merely inconsistent, but things will still work.

Understanding what it means for the model to be inconsistent, to have unsatisfiable classes, and other OWL (DL really) specific constructs, you should review the DL handbook.  Chapter 2 is particularly good.

If by appropriate you mean integrity constraints akin to what you'd have in a relational system, well, it doesn't work like that.  The open world assumption makes that a bit tricky, you can't really get the behavior you might expect without "closing" the world.  There's a good discussion of this on [Pellet's ICV page](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/icv/), and implementation of which is currently in [Stardog](http://stardog.com/docs/sdp/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I know how to work with jena model. But until now I have worked only with Foaf onthology. With owl I don't think is it the same way.

Comment: No, you can manipulate an OntModel the same way you manipulate any model, whether or not it contains OWL.  OntModel contains some OWL-specific functions, but you don't need to use them.  You can check the javadocs for reference on how to use OntModel.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you wanted to add data into model.

You can add statements to the model as

```
 model.add(statement);
```

or another model itself as

```
 model.add(newModel);
```

Hope this will help you.